# inApp purchase product name change

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

If I change the "Display" name of a inApp purchase product, I see the label "Pending".
Does this means I have to wait 7 days more for approval?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not always 7 days but you need to wait for review.

Comment: Is the IAP under the original name still purchasable in the mean time?  Once it is approved, does it go live immediately or do we have to manage the release of it?  Thanks!

Comment: @MobileVet The IAP is still purchasable while it is in the pending status with the old name/description. I don't think you can manage the release date of the new name, it will go live once it is approved.